# VMWare Workstation slow network performance

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm running a Host OS of Windows 8.1 with VMWare Workstation v10 and a Guest OS of Ubuntu 13.

Ubuntu has plenty of resources available to it (8GB/32GB RAM allocation and 2/4 Cores of an Intel i7) so it's got plenty of headroom. Also, the entire network is 100% gigabit throughout so there's no possibility for a network bottleneck (I'm the only user currently).

I configured both the Host and Guess OS to share a directory over the network and asked a separate machine to access them and upload/download a 5GB file. The Windows share was able to get ~100MB/s read/write and Ubuntu only got a mere ~20MB/s read/write.

So what's up with that?

My troubleshooting included the share directory location for Ubuntu, initially was a virtual disk, then changed to a physical drive within the VM settings with no difference in performance. Also, the VM is configured to use a bridged connection (a separate IP on the main network is crucial) so I haven't attempted to try a NAT connection, however I don't think this is the cause.

Any ideas as to what's causing the bottleneck in speeds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is VMWorkstation limitation. You can't get the whole bandwidth for one specific VM. That is acceptable for developement and for production there is ESXi.

Comment: So what software do you recommend to overcome this? Is there a different version of VMWare I should use?

Comment: If you definitely need a fast network connection for VM you have to use VMWare ESXi baremetal hypervisor that is fully compatible with VMWorkstation and intended for production use. Also ESXi is absolutely free for commertial purposes as well as VMWare viClient management tool. The minor disadvantage of ESXi is its hardware requirements - not all NICs and HDAs are supported.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity but I'm having trouble installing it/finding the right thing. I've been attempting to install this: http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor yet I don't understand why I'm being asked to create a boot medium/install on a separate drive; so I called it quits and figured I'm doing something horribly wrong. What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: ESXi is the tiny linux that have the only application preinstalled - hypervisor. On install it creates really small bootable partition for itself. After installation you can access it from console to set the basic parameters. All the rest functionality is accessible remotely via viClient.

Comment: So this is the ISO that I downloaded from that page right?

Comment: Log into VMWare site and check the link https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/evalcenter?lp=default&p=free-esxi5 here you'll find all distros an your free licence key

Comment: I downloaded both the ISO and EXE. The EXE installed the vSphere Client, yet thats currently useless as it won't connect to anything. The ISO makes me install it on a bootable USB to the install it on a bootable media which then runs on the PC on its own without windows. What exactly am I doing wrong? Sorry for the hassle, new to the world of virtualisation beyond end-user VM's.

Comment: Unless I'm meant to download the 3rd option - CD image for Linux Guest OSes?

Comment: ESXi can be installed on the small media but you'll need bigger media to store your VMs. You can try ESXi inside VMWWorkstation - it works pretty well with 2G of RAM and 16G+ of HDD.

Comment: Which one do I download? and how exactly do I try ESXi inside Workstation?

Comment: Create custom VM with CDROM attached to the ISO image. Boot VM and installation begins automatically.

Comment: Ohh, so I'm creating a virtual machine of ESXi right?

Comment: Just for the training. For production ESXi should be installed on the real hardware.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your help :) Mind if you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is VMWorkstation limitation. You can't get the whole bandwidth for one specific VM. That is acceptable for developement and for production purposes ESXi should be used.